# Excel vba - paste below header

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy a column from one workbook to another.

```
y.Sheets("data").Range("A2:A1048576").Clear 'delete contents of target columns first  
x.Sheets("file").Range("C:C").Copy 'copy column from another sheet
y.Sheets("data").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

I'm trying to paste it to starting from `A2` since `A1` is my header.

I'm getting a `application-defined or object-defined error`

Comment: Can you show more of your code? Also, which line throws the error?

Comment: it getting the error from the paste part of the code.

Comment: Again, we need to see more of your code. But my thought would be, if you already know that you want to paste from `A2`, why not just use that as your starting range instead of using `Offset`? (i.e. `y.Sheets("data").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: this is pretty much it, before those lines, all I do is open the workbooks. I tried `y.Sheets("data").Range("A:A").paste` and its working but it overwrites the header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is you copy a complete column `Range("C:C").Copy` and that means you have to paste to a complete column otherwise it would not fit in and exceed Excel's maximum row count.

Therefore I suggest to copy only that part of column C that contains data:

```
With x.Sheets("file")
    .Range("C1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Copy
End With
```

This copies only from C1 to the last used cell. And then you can paste it directly to A2

```
y.Sheets("data").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 1):

It's best practice not to reference entire columns (some million cells) when you don't need to:

```
With y.Sheets("data") ' reference sheet "data" in workbook 'y'
    .Range("A2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).ClearContents ' clear 'referenced sheet column "A" cells from row 2 down to last not empty one
End With
With x.Sheets("file") ' reference sheet "file" in workbook 'x'
    With .Range("C1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)) 'reference referenced sheet column "C" cells from row 1 down to last not empty one
        y.Sheets("data").Range("A2").Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = .Value ' paste referenced range values to workbook "y" sheet "data" starting from cell A2
    End With
End With
```

Comment: @ErinSantos; did you try this?

Answer (score 1):

Or the following

```
With y.Sheets("data")
    Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("A")).Clear
    Intersect(x.Sheets("file").UsedRange, x.Sheets("file").Columns("C")).Copy .Range("A2")
End With
```